# Categorize Columns in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset (Excel) with the results of customer satisfaction questionnaires over several years.

The questions in the Excel are each a column, and every row is the value of the response (value 1 to 5).
However, those questions are separated in categories (eg. questions about "communication", "quality",...).
I'd like to find a way to have these columns "grouped" or "categorized" into categories, but can't wrap my head around it. It felt like a thing to do with hierarchies but that is clearly not the way to go.

UPDATED with sample data:
[Image of excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbOca.png)

| Quality performance | Company perception | Communication |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Quality Q1 Quality Q2 Quality Q3 | Company Q1 CompanyQ2 | Response Time Correct Capable |

| Responder | Quality Q1 | Quality Q2 | Quality Q3 | Company Q1 | CompanyQ2 | Response Time | Correct Capable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Client 1 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 5 | 1 | 2 |
| Client 2 | 2 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 1 | 4 | 3 |
| Client 3 | 5 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 3 |
| Client 4 | 0 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 4 |
| Client 5 | 0 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 5 |
| Client 6 | 5 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 3 |
| Client 7 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Client 8 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 5 | 4 | 5 |
| Client 9 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 5 |
| Client 10 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 0 | 2 | 3 |
| Client 11 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 0 | 0 |

On PowerBI I'd like to have a score per category on which I can drill down to get into deeper detail.

Comment: provide sample data and expected output

Comment: Edited with a screenshot of the data.

Comment: follow this [How To](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post)

Comment: that's as close as I'm going to get to mimic the table

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
let
  Source = Table.FromRows(
    Json.Document(
      Binary.Decompress(
        Binary.FromText(
          "ZZC7DoQgEEV/xVBbyMi+ar/AbY2FcSlIFIxisX+/qwzmisWEucPJnUfTiLdeJmc/eha5qNduMP6b1RIFoSj/onLj1FnGDkFBjKs1feeNs1mwXvTlo3LzrHsv2rwR1WC09dlmVXDc4N3qhCDthfC5RcmQ2nMAS3CIueL8BCpup9g56pADGOeS7EbsFmYF8A5AAUFp6wcX4wLy2DgBn8lc8Twqbf0CgMDxMqMsoJdK7E+9JVJ4xbBW2/4A",
          BinaryEncoding.Base64
        ),
        Compression.Deflate
      )
    ),
    let
      _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true])
    in
      type table [
        Column1 = _t,
        #"Quality performance" = _t,
        Column3 = _t,
        Column4 = _t,
        #"Company perception" = _t,
        Column6 = _t,
        Communication = _t,
        Column8 = _t
      ]
  ),
  ct = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
    Source,
    {
      {"Column1", type text},
      {"Quality performance", type text},
      {"Column3", type text},
      {"Column4", type text},
      {"Company perception", type text},
      {"Column6", type text},
      {"Communication", type text},
      {"Column8", type text}
    }
  ),
  DH = Table.DemoteHeaders(ct),
  CT = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
    DH,
    {
      {"Column1", type text},
      {"Column2", type text},
      {"Column3", type text},
      {"Column4", type text},
      {"Column5", type text},
      {"Column6", type text},
      {"Column7", type text},
      {"Column8", type text}
    }
  ),
  KFR = Table.FirstN(CT, 1),
  TT = Table.Transpose(KFR),
  AC = Table.AddColumn(
    TT,
    "Custom",
    each
      if [Column1] = "Column1" then
        ct[Column1]{0}
      else if Text.Contains([Column1], "Column") then
        null
      else
        [Column1]
  ),
  RTR = Table.Skip(AC, 1),
  FD = Table.FillDown(RTR, {"Custom"}),
  #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(ct, [PromoteAllScalars = true]),
  #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(
    #"Promoted Headers",
    {"Responder"},
    "Attribute",
    "Value"
  ),
  #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns",
    {"Responder"},
    {{"ad", each _, type table [Responder = nullable text, Attribute = text, Value = text]}}
  ),
  #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(
    #"Grouped Rows",
    "Custom",
    each
      let
        src = [ad],
        Index = Table.AddIndexColumn(src, "Index", 0, 1),
        Add = Table.AddColumn(Index, "Custom", each FD[Custom]{[Index]}),
        Remove = Table.RemoveColumns(Add, {"Index"}),
        #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(
          Remove,
          "Custom.1",
          each List.Difference(Text.Split([Attribute], " "), Text.Split([Custom], " "))
        ),
        #"Expanded Custom.1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom.1"),
        #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(
          #"Expanded Custom.1",
          {{"Custom", "CAT"}, {"Custom.1", "SubCat"}}
        ),
        #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns", {"Attribute"}),
        #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns", {{"Value", type number}})
      in
        #"Changed Type"
  ),
  #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Custom"}),
  #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
    #"Removed Other Columns",
    "Custom",
    {"Responder", "Value", "CAT", "SubCat"},
    {"Responder", "Value", "CAT", "SubCat"}
  )
in
  #"Expanded Custom"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the first step is to unpivot your table so you have one row per item following this pattern.  [Microsoft Docs - Unpivot columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/unpivot-column).  Will create code something like this:

```
=Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Responder"}, "Question", "Response")
```

You can then create a "Question" table with a "Question" column and a "Group".  Join the question table to your unpivoted table by the question, and you can now report on your questions and groups.